# input:email in js

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

I have a contact form that uses recaptcha v2. I have use the default "requirement" verification by adding required in the form input tag:

```
<label for="formAuthor">
    Name<span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="formAuthor" id="formAuthor" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['formAuthor']))  echo $_POST['formAuthor'];?>" size="40" required>
```

I uses a `.js` to fade the label away when the field is on focus. 
But if I set the `input type` to `"email"`  (to get the correct verification from Recaptcha) the fade away effect doesn't work anymore.

Here is how the revelent part of the `.js`

```
$jformItems = $j("input:text, textarea");
```

I've tried to add input: email but with success.

```
$jformItems = $j("input:text, input:email, textarea");
```

Any idea how I can get this .js to work with the `input:email` ?

Answer: based on sacreyoule answer this is what solved it!

```
$jformItems = $j("input:text, input[type=email], textarea");
```

Comment: You don't get any errors on your console like `unsupported pseudo: email` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your issue but have you tried :
`$j("input[type=email]")` ?

Comment: Your welcome, can you check the topic as resolved to let it disappear in the flow of resolved topic :D